# "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" when trying to access a repository on github

Tags: github, ssl-certificate

All of a sudden when accessing a repo on github using a git command I'm getting:

$ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXXXX': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I worked just fine for years. I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using a non-default antivirus or firewall, any monitoring software, or any type of proxy whatever?  Are you using a network with any sort of TLS MITM device?

Comment: Not sure, this is a company laptop. I've asked other co-workers, they don't have the same problem. I've opened a ticket with helpdesk but they have been very slow.